# I need to create table using C that takes input from user without using Arrays, Dynamic Arrays, or Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c

I am not allowed to use arrays nor anything else I have not yet studied in the course, e.g: pointers, dynamic memory allocations, etc. What I have studied so far is: Functions and loops. I need to list all of the course codes, days, and times for as many courses as the user has specified in the first `scanf_s` call. I have no idea how to proceed without using arrays. Any hints/help would be appreciated.

```
printf("Please enter the number of courses you'd like to take: ");
int numOfCourses;
scanf_s("%d", &numOfCourses);
int courseCode;
int courseDay;
int courseTime;

int i = 0;
while (i < numOfCourses) {
  printf("Please enter the code of the course: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &courseCode);
  printf("Please enter the day of the course: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &courseDay);
  printf("Please enter the time of the course: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &courseTime);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: what does *list of all course codes* mean? BTW, you can start with using some good indentation in your code.

Comment: Yeah the formatting got all messed up when I copied it to here. Basically, the user must specify how many courses he has, and must enter the code for all the courses alongside their times and days using only integers. The program must create a table from all the user inputs; I don't know how to save the user's inputs without using an array, though.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the return value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: Those functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers. or EOF.  Any returned value other than the number of expected conversion specifiers indicates an error occurred.

Comment: what is the max number of courses that a student can take?

Comment: @BallenAbdullah you can fix indentation in your question then. As for the table, you still need to explain a bit more. What is this table? in a file? on the screen? on a web page? You cannot have it on the screen from which you get inputs without disallowed data struct or intermediate saving it into a file.

Comment: hmm.. I don't understand the point of such a question nor constraint.  I certainty don't see the value of it to the community; and if I'm being completely honest, I am inclined to believe you've misinterpreted your instructions here on this assignment.  It could be that such instructions and assignments are meant to raise discussion.  It could also be that whom ever assigned this thinks strings aren't an array by definition.. or some silliness.

Comment: From the instructor's instructions:
Assume every course takes just one hour and starts at one of the following time slots: 8:00, 10:00, 12:00, 14:00 and 16:00.  
Make your code robust and easy to read.
Please upload your code as plain text to Moodle.
You are NOT allowed to use a tool/feature that has not been studied in ITE202 yet, e.g. arrays, etc.
You are NOT allowed to work in a group for this assignment. Plagiarism/cheating will not be tolerated in any way, shape or form. Give it your best shot and avoid getting dismissed from the class.

Comment: @BallenAbdullah is that the whole text of the exercise or is there something else? For example i don't see where it's stated that the course must include code, date, time and that those must be ```int```. Also what is the format for the course code? Is it just a one digit number, any length of digit, only numbers or letters too?

Comment: @BrettCaswell a professor in one of my courses used to have assignments similar to this (although with more real world application constraints), they were mostly meant to make us think outside of the box instead of using the easy way out. I don't know if they are really useful but sometimes it's fun to try and find new (possibly dumb and really subpar) solutions to problems with unreasonable specifications.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show us **what is allowed**? It seems that you're still in the early stages, so it shouldn't be that much. Name all concepts you've learned so far.

Comment: @BallenAbdullah when you get the solution please post it somewhere,  I actually really like this type of exercises and i'm curious to see what the official solution would look like :)

Comment: @JohnSmith a couple of my classmates figured it out. The maximum amount of classes to be taken in our uni per semester is 6; you have to create as many functions for each number of classes a person takes. Not knowing that hint is detrimental to not solving the question; I missed out on it :(

Answer (score 0):

Suggest:

1) create a struct that holds all the info for an individual student
2) create a file, perhaps in the local directory or in `/tmp`
3) for each student, after collecting the information, write the struct to the file

--or--

given the MAX number of courses that a student can take, then code similar to:

```
int   course1day;
int   course1time;
int   course1code;
(repeat for MAX number of courses, increment the digit for each course)
```

a consideration is: what will the code be doing with this information after it is collected?

Comment: The max number of courses is unknown. How can I incorporate that into my code?

Comment: for max number of courses,  Suggest some large number that is beyond what a student could actually take,  For instance 20

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `courseCode` is a single digit number representing the course you could do something like this:

```
printf("Please enter the number of courses you'd like to take: ");
int numOfCourses;
scanf_s("%d", &numOfCourses);
int courseCode;
int courseDay;
int courseTime;

// unsigned long to have the most possible space
unsigned long courseCodeArray = 0;
unsigned long courseDayArray = 0;
unsigned long courseTimeArray = 0;

int i = 0;
while (i < numOfCourses) {
  // single digit code
  printf("Please enter the code of the course: "); 
  scanf_s("%d", &courseCode);

  // 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday , etc.
  printf("Please enter the day of the course: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &courseDay);

  // 1 = 8:00, 2 = 10:00, 3 = 12:00, etc.
  printf("Please enter the time of the course: ");
  scanf_s("%d", &courseTime);

  courseCodeArray += courseCode;
  courseDayArray += courseDay;
  courseTimeArray += courseTime;

  courseCodeArray = courseCodeArray * 10;
  courseDayArray =  courseDayArray * 10;
  courseTimeArray = courseTimeArray * 10;

  i++;
}
```

This way you would have an "array" made with a single int that could work as long as the code of the course is an integer between 1 and 9.

E.G. the numbers: `435` , `132` and `431`
Would mean: `4-1-4` `Course 4 Monday at 14:00` , `3-3-3` `Course 3 Wednesday at 12:00` and `5-2-1` `Course 5 Tuesday at 8:00` respectively.

Of course you then need to write some checks to ensure that the user will enter only valid numbers, that you don't go past the maximum `unsigned long` value and  make better design choices but i think this is what your professor meant by

> Make your code robust and easy to read

So I won't do absolutely everything for you ;)

With this you essentially store multiple values in a single `unsigned long` or `int` as long as you know how to "decode" the single digits to their representation. Just divide the arrays by 10 to remove the last 0 and then read digit by digit of the resulting "array" numbers and convert them back.